# Get WSAEFAULT error when I use getsockname

Tags: c, networking, ethernet, winsock2

When I run following code, I always get WSAEFAULT error. Not sure what am I doing wrong? Any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

```
uint8_t status = ICRON_OK;
struct sockaddr_in serverAddr, clientAddr;
int rc = 0;
int clen = sizeof(clientAddr);
int serverSocket;

if((serverSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP)) == INVALID_SOCKET)
{
    printf("Socket Creation failure\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

memset(&serverAddr, 0, sizeof(serverAddr));
serverAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
serverAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
serverAddr.sin_port = htons(ICONTROLNET_EVENT_PORT);

if(bind(serverSocket, (struct sockaddr *)&serverAddr, sizeof(serverAddr)) == SOCKET_ERROR)
{
    printf("bind failure\n");
    WSACleanup();
    closesocket(serverSocket);
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

if (getsockname(serverSocket, (struct sockaddr *)&serverAddr, (int *)sizeof(serverAddr)) != 0)
{  
    printf("GETSOCKNAME ERROR = %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
    //Here always get WSAEFAULT
}
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help should generally provide a [mre] of the problem, which includes a function `main` and all `#include` directives. This allows other people to easily test your program, by simply using copy&paste.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the official Microsoft documentation for the function [getsockname](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsock/nf-winsock-getsockname), when you get the error code `WSAEFAULT`, it means the following:

> The `name` or the `namelen` parameter is not a valid part of the user address space, or the `namelen` parameter is too small.

This documentation later states the following about the `namelen` parameter, which is the third parameter of `getsockname`:

> On call, the `namelen` parameter contains the size of the `name` buffer, in bytes. On return, the `namelen` parameter contains the actual size in bytes of the `name` parameter.

When the documentation uses the word "contains", it means that the pointer `namelen` should point to an `int` which specifies the size of the object pointed to by `name` (the second parameter).

You are passing the following expression as `namelen` (the third parameter):

```
(int *)sizeof(serverAddr)
```

This is wrong. It is correct to use the expression `sizeof serverAddr` or `sizeof(serverAddr)`. However, instead of casting that value to a pointer and passing that pointer directly to the function `getsockname`, you should instead pass a pointer to an `int` which contains the value `sizeof serverAddr`.

Therefore, you should change the line

```
if (getsockname(serverSocket, (struct sockaddr *)&serverAddr, (int *)sizeof(serverAddr)) != 0)
```

to:

```
int serverAddrSize = sizeof serverAddr;
if (getsockname(serverSocket, (struct sockaddr *)&serverAddr, &serverAddrSize) != 0)
```